# Dynamically identifying the type of file encoded by base64

Tags: java, base64

I am using java 8 base64 encode and decode library, while I am successfully encoding a jpg/pdf/png file and  able to again save that base64 string to jpg/pdf/png. But my requirement is detecting the file type dynamically and then saving that string to image file in its respective way. For example, if I  get a base64 pdf file then my application automatically detects that the string is Base64 pdf string, and save that string as pdf.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hey Anuj! Try reading the first bytes ("magic number") to guess the filetype. Be aware that this is not a guarantee and that all user  uploads should be considered as potentially bad. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files

Answer (score 1):

Most well known file types have "magic numbers" at the start of the file. These are bytes that identify the type of the file without needing to know the file extension. For example:

- All JPEGs begin with: FF D8 FF DB
- All PDFs begin with: 25 50 44 46 2d
- All PNGs begin with: 89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A

These were found on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures , but if this list doesn't contain a value for a format you need, you can look up the format's published specification.

Once you have decoded your base64 string, you can check the first bytes to see if they match these constants, and handle them appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: You can't by design read a format from a base64 encoded String as itself.
What you can do are two things depending on where you get the base64 Strings from.

### Adding Info to your encoder

Add filetype information to your encoded string, either the first X bits or the last X bits will do fine and read them from files you encoded first and decide on the bits what kind of file you have there.

### Reading the magic number

Each of the documents you mentioned have specific file-type-dependend beginnings of their file (headers/magic number). If you read the magic number, you can decide on that which filetype the file propably is (but never trust this decision). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files

Comment: The keyword here is magic number: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files

Comment: Right you are, I edited my answer according to that. Thanks!